# Omnipay / Paypal Receive Payment Without Account

Tags: php, paypal, omnipay

I need to receive payments via PayPal on my website and have used Omnipay (PayPal_Express) to implement it.

I also like my users to have the option to pay with their credit card without having to create an paypal account. In the sandbox this works great (the user has the option to log in or to enter credit card details).
When I switch to live the only options are to login or create an account.

- The setting to accept payments without account on the paypal website is set to on
- solutionType is set to "Sole"
- landingPage is set to "Billing"

My business account is from Austria and has a verfied bank account (but no credit card).

Does anybody know what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Live mode, credit card only payment is actually controlled by PayPal risk detection sysem randomly. In order to manage risk, PayPal may limit the Funding Sources available for a transaction. If we limit the Funding Sources, we will alert our users that there is a higher-than-normal level of risk associated with the payment. Such a notice does not mean that either party to the transaction is acting in a dishonest or fraudulent manner. It means there may be a higher-than-normal level of risk associated with the transaction. PayPal employs complex statistical models to identify patterns of behavior. This is similar to the way banks and credit card companies identify patterns of behavior that are out of the ordinary when approving individual transactions. When our system does not allow a certain funding source for a transaction, it is merely an indication that the individual transaction fits a pattern we have observed in the past to have a high risk of failure. In this situation, your customers can only sign up PayPal accounts or log into their existing PayPal accounts to make payments to you.